# Getting high rate of 503 errors with BigQuery Streaming API

Tags: google-bigquery

When using BigQuery Streaming API, we started to get today high rate of 503 errors as following:

```
{
  "code" : 503,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Connection error. Please try again.",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Connection error. Please try again."
}
                at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
                at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
                at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
                at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
                at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1049)
                at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
                at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
                at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
                at prtetl.logic.savers.WebDataSaverBase.sendDataToBigQuery(WebDataSaverBase.java:174)
                at prtetl.logic.savers.WebDataSaverBase.save(WebDataSaverBase.java:292)
                at prtetl.logic.parsers.JsErrorsDataFileParser.saveList(JsErrorsDataFileParser.java:91)
                at prtetl.logic.parsers.JsErrorsDataFileParser.access$000(JsErrorsDataFileParser.java:39)
                at prtetl.logic.parsers.JsErrorsDataFileParser$1.run(JsErrorsDataFileParser.java:69)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Does anyone else seeing this as well?